# Linux Perf and Task's memory usage if possible

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, profiling, perf

I am trying to create a stream of samples of resource utilization of selected tasks. For example a simple command line like this:

```
perf stat -I 400 -e task-clock,instructions,cycles
```

can give me a good measure of CPU utilization. I want to be able to get the same result for memory usage too (not considering the LLC stuff yet). Does "Linux Perf" able to do this? can I see how many pages are resident in memory for this task (number of pages if different kinds e.g. 4K, 1M, ...). Or how much of the pages are swapped?

Comment: Default mode of `perf` profiling is to profile on cpu time or cycles (and there are options for cache/tlb mis/hit counts, check `perf stat -d ./program`), so it will not say anything about memory usage (it can be used to trace some vm calls in the kernel). There are some tools to estimate WSS (working set size) over time from Brendan Gregg: http://www.brendangregg.com/wss.html. And some alternative malloc implementations may have integrated profiling: tcmalloc https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/heapprofile.html, jemalloc https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/wiki/Use-Case%3A-Heap-Profiling

Comment: @osgx thanks for the answer. You gave me some good resources which I was ignoring. I ended up with Brendan's approach.